# How to Flag Revision

Tags: support, flags

Is there a way to flag a revision for a moderator?

The edit on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51695450/2, should be rolled back but I don't have that option and don't see a way to flag just the edit.

Comment: I've rolledback to revision 1. If you need to support for these kind of actions (read users with full-edit privileges) on SO hop in to the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). They do have a [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) as well.